Why are there no no-attribution licenses other than "public domain"?
I regularly have the issue that I want to license some work in a way that it is free to use and modify, but copies and derivative works have to have the same or a compatible license. Sometimes I want to add for non-commercial use only.
But I do not want to add the requirement for attribution of the author¹.
Are there ready-made licenses for that? Or not? I do not find any.
If not: What is the reason? Legal reasons (all over the world?, or mainly in the US? How about the EU?)? Or that license creators just do not think that people do not want to be credited?
Taking the Creative Commons licenses as an example, the only "license" there without attribution requirement is CC0 (public domain).
If I want to add things like "ShareAlike" (SA) or "NonCommercial" (NC), I am always forced to also add "Attribution" (BY).
Regards!

¹: Some use cases to not want this can even by privacy concerns.

Regarding privacy concerns, copyright law allows works to be anonymous or pseudonymous. You don't have to use your own name or a designation that can be traced to you.

Is this for software or non-software works?

Creative Commons licenses without a BY clause actually used to be offered (e.g. https://creativecommons.org/licenses/sa/1.0/), but they were discontinued back in 2004: https://creativecommons.org/2004/05/25/announcingandexplainingournew20licenses/ – although that was simply for lack of demand, rather than any particularly principled reason.

See also this related Q&A: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/declaring-copyright-anonymously

Is this question specific to CC licenses? Perhaps the title should rather be "Why are there no CC licenses without attribution requirements other than CC0/public domain"?

CC0 not Public Domain (outside of a few lucky jurisdictions), and is a no-atttribution license. So that is one license, not no licenses.

@ruben2020: For both. What is the background of the question, what does change if it is for software, artwork, writing, ...?

@Brandin: General, but Creative Commons was the example which made the "issue" most clear for me. I am not a license expert, though. I see that GPL also intends to identify the creator of the work.

@GolarRamblar GPL s7 has an optional ability to require author attribution if you want, but without activating that explicitly, it does not take effect. I looked at the rest of GPLv3 and did not see anything that implies to me that the author/programmer must identifier herself in order to use that license. Taking someone else's GPL code and releasing a modified version anonymously as a program also seems like it would be fine to me, as long as you respect all of the terms in doing so.

@Brandin: I came to the conclusion because GPL 3.0 states under "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs": "Copyright (C)   [...]" -- so name of author to be stated and so distributed with the license text/ license information shipped with the project.

@GolarRamblar The "How to Apply ..." part is after the end of the terms and conditions, so it's basically just helpful advice. It's not a binding part of the license agreement. I looked again and I see that this is discussed in greater detail here for the GPLv3 part of your question: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/does-gplv3-require-attribution/

@Brandin: Ah OK. It sounds more binding to me (in a sense that, when I am not a legal expert, and do not follow the rules under "How to Apply", I might end up with actually not having licensed the work under GPL 3.0. With juristical stuff I always fear that making something different voids everything. I am not a law person and so cannot judge how it is in this case.) Thanks for clarifying!

Your request for non-attribution is already fulfilled by the following clause in CC-BY 4.0, CC-BY-SA 4.0 and other CC-BY licenses:

Section 3(a)(3):
If requested by the Licensor, You must remove any of the information
required by Section 3(a)(1)(A) to the extent reasonably practicable.

I will reproduce here the full Section 3(a), which is about License Conditions on Attribution:

Section 3 – License Conditions.
Your exercise of the Licensed Rights
is expressly made subject to the following conditions.
a. Attribution.

If You Share the Licensed Material (including in modified form), You must:

A. retain the following if it is supplied by the Licensor with the
Licensed Material:
i. identification of the creator(s) of the
Licensed Material and any others designated to receive attribution, in
any reasonable manner requested by the Licensor (including by
pseudonym if designated);
ii. a copyright notice;
iii. a
notice that refers to this Public License;
iv. a notice that
refers to the disclaimer of warranties;
v. a URI or hyperlink to
the Licensed Material to the extent reasonably practicable;
B. indicate if You modified the Licensed Material and retain an
indication of any previous modifications; and
C. indicate the Licensed Material is licensed under this Public
License, and include the text of, or the URI or hyperlink to, this
Public License.

You may satisfy the conditions in Section 3(a)(1) in any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context in which You Share the
Licensed Material. For example, it may be reasonable to satisfy the
conditions by providing a URI or hyperlink to a resource that includes
the required information.

If requested by the Licensor, You must remove any of the information required by Section 3(a)(1)(A) to the extent reasonably
practicable.

If You Share Adapted Material You produce, the Adapter's License You apply must not prevent recipients of the Adapted Material from
complying with this Public License.



By the way, non-commercial (NC) and non-derivatives (ND) are considered to be not open source based on the Open Source Definition of OSI. Although so, that's not the focus of the question.

Ah, @ruben2020, thanks for that find! The Creative Commons license chooser completely hides that fact for me (just says "Anyone using my work must include proper attribution." in step 2) and makes me assume that crediting the author is mandatory. (I know that a pseudonym or a random identifier could be used always, but that for me sounds like a dirty hack and nothing within the intended use case of the license. I feel much more comfortable if a license actively acknowledges if I do not want to be credited.)

@GolarRamblar may I suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL - I don't know how much more active you can ack that you don't want to be credited.

@WayneWerner this too does not include the requirement to license derived work or copies under the same or a similar license. What I searched for was a no-attribution license which allows copies and derivative works still requires those to be licensed similarly!

The problem with a Creative Commons ShareAlike license without an attribution clause is not only do you prevent yourself from being identified, you would prevent any other contributors from having their attribution retained if they wish it, because the work is licensed under your putative "CC-SA" license, not CC-BY-SA. That could be worked around by allowing CC-SA to "upgrade" itself to CC-BY-SA, but that's adding a lot of complication and potential confusion for a niche use case.
The privacy concerns you raise are already dealt because the CC-BY-SA license requires you to attribute the creator only if that information is supplied (section 3.A.1 of the license). If someone doesn't want to be identified, they can just release a work without including that information.

In a nutshell: as author, one can freely decide which information the "BY" attribution has to include, be it a proper name + homepage + contact details, a chosen pseudonym (e.g. a GitHub username) or simply "Anonymous", "N.N." or "".

@ojdo: In Germany, that is even an explicitly recognized Moral Right, regardless of license. The author can always decide whether and how to be named.

Ah, @Philip Kendall, thanks for that find! The Creative Commons license chooser completely hides that fact for me (just says "Anyone using my work must include proper attribution." in step 2) and makes one assume that crediting the author is mandatory. (I know that a pseudonym or a random identifier could be used always, but that for me sounds like a dirty hack and nothing within the intended use case of the license. I feel much more comfortable if a license actively acknowledges if I do not want to be credited.)

An alternative no-attribution license is MIT-0: https://opensource.org/license/mit-0.
This license has the MIT license wording, but without the attribution requirement. https://github.com/aws/mit-0 explains the motivation behind it:

This license has proven useful for code that is intended for developers to use as reference, teaching samples, examples, or templates that other developers may modify for their own purposes.
In many of these cases, the initial developer may not want to impose even the cost of attribution, or the use cases may not be conducive to attribution.
The CC0 and various "do what you want" licenses and various public domain dedications may be less attractive to the initial developer for various reasons (i.e., a license is preferable to a public domain dedication). The MIT license with all the attribution requirement language removed fills this need.


Nice first contribution: spot-on relevant, well-referenced, but containing all pertinent material as well.  Thank you, and I hope you keep it up.  +1 from me!

Thanks; however, this does not include a "share-alike" functionality: In MIT-0, I do not find any requirements that derived work must be licensed under same or compatible license.

Strictly speaking, this question is about licenses that do not require attribution (but are copyleft), not licenses that forbid attribution.
Philip Kendall’s answer correctly points out that Creative Commons (CC) licenses (at least version 4.0) already provide a way for the licensor to grant an exception from the attribution requirement. For clarity, here is the relevant section, section 3(a)(1)(A), with the relevant part emphasised: ‘If You Share the Licensed Material (including in modified form), You must: retain the following if it is supplied by the Licensor with the Licensed Material: …’. Also, ruben2020’s answer correctly points out that CC licenses (at least version 4.0) have a provision for requiring the removal of attribution.
But both of those answers depend on very specific provisions in CC licenses, and neither is convenient. If you simply omit attribution information, licensees might waste time searching for it; if you try to combine a CC license with a requirement to remove attribution, it is just confusing (at best).
There is a better, more general answer. As the licensor, you choose what terms to license your material under; you can simply grant exceptions from any license requirements that you do not like!
CC licenses do not have a specific provision for this, but the license terms do sort of acknowledge it. Quoting from the CC BY-SA 4.0 legal code, section 8(c) says (emphasis added):

No term or condition of this Public License will be waived and no failure to comply consented to unless expressly agreed to by the Licensor.

The General Public License (GPL) is preferred for software. That license (at least version 3) has a general provision allowing the licensor to grant exceptions from any of the usual license requirements. Quoting from GPL 3, section 7 starts:

“Additional permissions” are terms that supplement the terms of this License by making exceptions from one or more of its conditions. Additional permissions that are applicable to the entire Program shall be treated as though they were included in this License, to the extent that they are valid under applicable law. If additional permissions apply only to part of the Program, that part may be used separately under those permissions, but the entire Program remains governed by this License without regard to the additional permissions.


Why would you need 'additional permissions' to allow someone to make anonymous versions of your GPL'ed code? I looked at the license text and did not see any requirement to identify yourself as it currently stands. The only possible thing is the requirement to state which parts of the program you modified, but that requirement can surely be fulfilled anonymously.
